# How to use ansible playbook to install maven?

Tags: maven, ansible

```
- name: Download Apache Maven
  get_url: url=http://apache.claz.org/maven/maven-3/3.1.1/binaries/apache-maven--bin.tar.gz dest=/tmp/apache-maven--bin.tar.gz

- name: Untar Maven
  shell: chdir=/tmp creates=/opt/apache-maven- tar -zxf apache-maven--bin.tar.gz -C /opt
```

Then, what should I do to install maven?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can either update the `$PATH` to link to the downloaded *maven* files:

```
# your two commands

- name: Download Apache Maven 
  get_url: url=http://apache.claz.org/maven/maven-3/3.1.1/binaries/apache-maven--bin.tar.gz dest=/tmp/apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz

- name: Untar Maven 
  shell: chdir=/tmp creates=/opt/apache-maven-3.1.1 tar -zxf apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz -C /opt

# What is missing

- name: Update path for maven use
  shell: export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin:$PATH
```

Or simply install *maven* (if you don't need a very specific version) from the depots:

```
- name: install maven (and other packages if needed)
  become: yes
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600
  with_items:
    - maven
```

(**Note:** here you can install other packages by adding items in the `with_items`)

Answer (score 0):

Now days you can rely on roles published in galaxy. [Search there](https://galaxy.ansible.com/search?deprecated=false&keywords=maven&order_by=-relevance&page=1) to check

For example this: https://galaxy.ansible.com/tecris/maven

Answer (score 0):

here is my version of installing Maven ans setting environment variables using ansible

```
---
- hosts: BackEndServers

  tasks:
  - name: Update APT package manager repositories cache
    become: true
    apt:
      update_cache: yes

  - name: Download Apache Maven
    become: true
    get_url: url=https://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/maven/maven-3/3.8.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.1-bin.tar.gz dest=/tmp/apache-maven-3.8.1-bin.tar.gz

  - name: Untar Maven
    become: true 
    shell: chdir=/tmp creates=/opt/apache-maven-3.8.1 tar -zxf apache-maven-3.8.1-bin.tar.gz -C /opt

  - name: Set MAVEN_HOME
    become: true
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
      create: yes
      state: present
      mode: '0744'
      line: '{{ item }}'
    with_items:
      - 'export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.8.1'
      - 'export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.8.1'
      - 'export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}'
```